# Command line options of rackup are not shown in ps output or procfs

Tags: command-line, ps, proc, ruby

As you know if you wish to get command-line runtime arguments for running command you can parse `ps -e` or `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`.

But I have encountered issue when this method returns only command with path but without arguments.
For example:

```
$ rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production

Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop

$ ps -e | grep rackup

16226 ttys001    0:02.19 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@gearup/
bin/rackup  

$ xargs -0 echo < /proc/16226/cmdline

/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@gearup/bin/rackup
```

There are no `private_pub.ru` and subsequent arguments.

Can `rackup` "swallow" options and make them invisible to `ps`?

What is reason for this behavior?
My main issue is to find certain process with certain argument with `ps` or `procfs`.

Output for `strace -rf -e trace=process rackup`

```
0.000000 execve("/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/bin/rackup", ["rackup", "private_pub.ru", "-s", "thin", "-E", "production"], [/* 89 vars */]) = 0
     0.003323 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f1f1b1b1740) = 0
     0.001193 execve("/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@gearup/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper", ["ruby_noexec_wrapper", "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p"..., "private_pub.ru", "-s", "thin", "-E", "production"], [/* 89 vars */]) = 0
     0.002065 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f04829a8740) = 0
     0.001028 execve("/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@gearup/bin/ruby", ["ruby", "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p"..., "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p"..., "private_pub.ru", "-s", "thin", "-E", "production"], [/* 89 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.000294 execve("/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/bin/ruby", ["ruby", "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p"..., "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p"..., "private_pub.ru", "-s", "thin", "-E", "production"], [/* 89 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.000286 execve("/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby", ["ruby", "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p"..., "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p"..., "private_pub.ru", "-s", "thin", "-E", "production"], [/* 89 vars */]) = 0
     0.005911 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f4c84595740) = 0
     0.013703 clone(Process 9182 attached
child_stack=0x7f4c845c1fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f4c845c29d0, tls=0x7f4c845c2700, child_tidptr=0x7f4c845c29d0) = 9182

>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
```

Comment: `ps` options vary a lot between various implementations. On my Linux system `ps -e` doesn't display full command line either. Have you tried `ps aux` (you need something that includes `-o cmd`)?

Comment: I tried `ps` on different systems (debian, macosx) with different options (`aux`, `axf` etc), but the result is always the same. I can observe options for other commands.
Stupid question, but can `rackup` "swallow" options and make invisible for os?

Comment: Does your prompt return after starting `rackup`? Maybe rackup starts a second daemonized process in background without arguments...

Comment: @user3777 as @binfalse suggests, if `rackup` forks off another process and passes it the parameters in another way, you are out of luck.

Comment: You can confirm whether `rackup` forks by comparing PIDs:
`rackup your_arguments;echo $!` Compare the resulting PID with the one in the `ps` output.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't stated your OS, and `ps` is quite OS-specific (and on Linux, distribution specific). Both Linux and FreeBSD at least match your usage of `/proc`.
`ps -e` outputs only `comm` (the possibly truncated "command") not the arguments.

On Linux or *BSD try for `ps`:

```
ps axwwo "pid ppid uid comm args"
```

`args` is the field you likely need, and the double "w" options allow "unlimited width" of output. The full path may exceed the available space (`ps` prefers one line per-process, and checks your terminal width), so you won't necessarily see the full path or arguments.

However, your use of `/proc/xx/cmdline` is correct, there simply are no arguments.

The second problem likely arises from the `rackup` executable being a shell script, I'm guessing that the script is short-lived and that the arguments get sucked into Ruby's `ARGV`. You can try

```
strace -rf -e trace=process rackup ...
```

to see what's happening.

You should be able to use rackup's `-P` or `--pid` option to record a PID file for each instance, then you can monitor and distinguish specific instances if that's what you are trying to do.

In general though `pgrep` or `pidof` are the best tools for identifying processes by name and/or arguments.

Comment: Output for `strace` is posted above. As I understand `rackup` runs `ruby` , that replaces parent `rackup`-process with itself and clears `rackup` name from ps output. Am i going the right way of thinking?

Comment: Yes, `execve()` replaces the running process, the process table entries (name and args) are updated accordingly. You can see the arguments being passed to `ruby`. If you don't see the arguments in `ps` or `proc` for the ruby process, then perhaps it's being overwrittn: both can be modified by the process itself, even in [Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450620/change-the-ruby-process-name-in-top)). This is commonly used to show state, or current requests.

Comment: Now I see, thnx

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely start reading [man-pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page). An example from `man ps` ([online man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps)):

```
-f     Do full-format listing. This option can be combined with many other UNIX-style options to add additional columns.  It also causes the command arguments to be printed.  When
       used with -L, the NLWP (number of threads) and LWP (thread ID) columns will be added.  See the c option, the format keyword args, and the format keyword comm.
```

Thus, try to run `ps -ef | grep rackup` ;-)

Comment: I read it definitely.

    `$ ps -ef | grep rack | grep -v grep`

    Output: `501 19895   374   0 12:43   ttys001    0:01.05 /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@gearup/bin/rackup`

Answer (score 0):

Certainly programs can access (change and delete) their arguments.  That is considered a security feature, especially when user names, passwords, and other sensitive information might be exposed.  Addresses, ports, shared memory keys, and other information can be considered sensitive also.

Daemon processes and other servers which fork/exec child processes also can shed arguments as part of their processing.